# Como recorres dos fechas en un for y luego compararlas

Tags: php, php7

Buenos días tengo 4 fechas que necesito recorrer en 2 for las dos primeras son las fechas que me digita el usuario  y las otras dos son las fechas en las que no se pueden hacer reservas, tengo el siguiente código pero cuando coloco una fecha en la que si se puede hacer reserva, entra en la condición de que no se puede hacer reserva, alguien me puede ayudar como corrijo esto.
Ejemplo de Fechas

```
$FechaInicioCanje = '16-04-2022';
$FechaFinCanje = '17-04-2022';
$fechaInicioBloqueoCanje= '18-04-2022';
$fechaFinBloqueoCanje = '20-04-2022';  

 if (!empty($FechaInicioBloqueoCanje) && !empty($FechaFinBloqueoCanje)) :
                    $fechaInicioBloqueoCanje = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje));
                    $fechaFinBloqueoCanje = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $FechaFinBloqueoCanje));

                    $diaFinalCanje = strtotime('+' . $CantidadDias . 'day', strtotime($FechaInicio));
                    $FechaInicioCanje = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $FechaInicio));
                    $FechaFinCanje = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $diaFinalCanje));

                    for ($i = $FechaInicioCanje; $i <= $FechaFinCanje; $i += 86400) {
                        for ($j = $fechaInicioBloqueoCanje; $j <= $fechaFinBloqueoCanje; $j += 86400) {


                            if ($i ==  $j) {

                                $respuesta["message"] = "No se pueden hacer canjes en la fecha seleccionada Fecha Inicio Bloqueo:" . $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje . " Fecha Fin Bloqueo:" . $FechaFinBloqueoCanje;
                                $respuesta["success"] = false;
                                $respuesta["response"] = null;
                                return $respuesta;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

```
 if (!empty($FechaInicioBloqueoCanje) && !empty($FechaFinBloqueoCanje)) :
                    $fechaInicioBloqueoCanje = $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje;
                    $fechaFinBloqueoCanje = $FechaFinBloqueoCanje;

                    $FechaInicioCanje = $FechaInicio;
                    $Dias = $CantidadDias - 1;
                    $diaFinalCanje = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($FechaInicioCanje . '+' . $Dias . ' day'));
                    $FechaFinCanje =  $diaFinalCanje;

                    //recorremos las fechas que selecciono el usuario
                    for ($i = $FechaInicioCanje; $i <= $FechaFinCanje; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i . "+ 1 day"))) {

                        //recorremos las fechas en donde no se permite hacer canjes
                        for ($j = $fechaInicioBloqueoCanje; $j <= $fechaFinBloqueoCanje; $j = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($j . "+ 1 day"))) {

                            if ($i ==  $j) {
                                $respuesta["message"] = "No se pueden hacer canjes en la fecha seleccionada Fecha Inicio Bloqueo:" . $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje . " Fecha Fin Bloqueo:" . $FechaFinBloqueoCanje;
                                $respuesta["success"] = false;
                                $respuesta["response"] = null;
                                return $respuesta;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes la comparación de si las fechas están entre el bloqueo

```
$FechaInicioCanje = '16-04-2022';
$FechaFinCanje = '17-04-2022';
$FechaInicioBloqueoCanje= '15-04-2022';
$FechaFinBloqueoCanje = '20-04-2022';  

 if (!empty($FechaInicioBloqueoCanje) && !empty($FechaFinBloqueoCanje)){
     if(fechaCanje($FechaInicioCanje, $FechaFinCanje, $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje, $FechaFinBloqueoCanje)){
        $respuesta["message"] = "No se pueden hacer canjes en la fecha seleccionada Fecha Inicio Bloqueo:" . $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje . " Fecha Fin Bloqueo:" . $FechaFinBloqueoCanje;
        $respuesta["success"] = false;
        $respuesta["response"] = null;
        print_r($respuesta);
    }else{
        echo 'Se puede hacer el canje';
    }
 }
 
 
 
 function fechaCanje($f_inicio, $f_fin, $f_inicio_bloqueo, $f_fin_bloqueo):bool{
     return dateIsInBetween(new DateTime($f_inicio_bloqueo), new DateTime($f_fin_bloqueo), new DateTime($f_inicio)) &&
     dateIsInBetween(new DateTime($f_inicio_bloqueo), new DateTime($f_fin_bloqueo), new DateTime($f_fin));
 }
 
 function dateIsInBetween(\DateTime $from, \DateTime $to, \DateTime $compareDate)
{
    return $compareDate->getTimestamp() > $from->getTimestamp() && $compareDate->getTimestamp() < $to->getTimestamp();
}
```

Te dejo también el código [aquí en live](https://paiza.io/projects/uoIXfpJze2kgEDsvBGovqA) para que lo pruebes u modifiques si lo necesitas. Ten en cuenta que cuando tu hacias el return del array yo he puesto un print_r para que se vea en el ejemplo que te he puesto.

Comment: es que necesito recorrer las fechas que el usuario digito para compararlas con las fechas en donde no se puede hacer reserva y decirle al usuario si en esa fecha se puede o no realizar la reserva

Comment: Y no sería mejor comparar que la fechas de inico y fin esten entre las de inicioBloqueo y finBloqueo? Te pongo un ejemplo en la respuesta

Comment: puse las fechas asi $FechaInicioCanje = '16-04-2022';
$FechaFinCanje = '18-04-2022';
$FechaInicioBloqueoCanje= '18-04-2022';
$FechaFinBloqueoCanje = '20-04-2022';  
y entra en el else de que si se puede y no deberia entrar debido a que esa fecha comienza el bloqueo

Comment: Aplica la negacion al if en ese caso,      if(!fechaCanje($FechaInicioCanje, $FechaFinCanje, $FechaInicioBloqueoCanje, $FechaFinBloqueoCanje)){